# Map entries to JSON conversion using GSON is not passing all the entries in the request

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to convert JSON request data to JSON string using GSON. For that I am using map. But I can see, some map entries are getting ignored in the request.

```
String jsonStrReq = null;
Map<String, String> patient1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        patient1.put("diagnosis", diagnosis);
        patient1.put("doctorId", Prefs.getString("docid", ""));
        patient1.put("patientId", null);
        patient1.put("patientName", name);
        patient1.put("patientUhid", uhid);
        patient1.put("mobileNumber", phone);
        patient1.put("age", age);
        patient1.put("gender", gender);
        patient1.put("area", area);
        patient1.put("city", city);
        patient1.put("tagColor", tagColor);
        patient1.put("treatments", treatment);
        patient1.put("profilePic", null);
        Gson gsonReq = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        jsonStrReq = gsonReq.toJson(patient1);
        Log.d("Testing", "Add Patient passed json  "+jsonStrReq);
```

The request string I am printing is coming as:

```
Add Patient passed json  {"area":"fhghf","patientName":"chfnb","gender":"Female","city":"gjfhhf","tagColor":"Red","doctorId":"32","patientUhid":"cbfjcg","mobileNumber":"xxxxxxxx","age":"25"}
```

If you see few entries are completely missing. Just want to know what is the wrong thing I am doing here.
Please help

Comment: Because your value are null. If you want also include null value in your json. You must tell to your gson instance to induce null value. Dont remember the méthode name, but I'm sure there is one.

Comment: I have already used serializeNulls()

Comment: Also the values which are not null, they are not coming

Comment: Nice question!, Could you also provide a debug log of the contents of the HashMap ? Although the HashMap has no special rules regarding null values, I am curious to see if it is added correctly.

Comment: Please also provide the version of gson that is used.

Comment: Log I have added already.

Comment: gson version used is 2.8.6

Comment: Add Patient passed json  {"area":"fhghf","patientName":"chfnb","gender":"Female","city":"gjfhhf","tagColor":"Red","doctorId":"32","patientUhid":"cbfjcg","mobileNumber":"xxxxxxxx","age":"25"}

Comment: Above is the request getting printed.

Comment: Using `Map`, and particularly `HashMap`, instead of DTO is (more than usually) a very bad choice: no structuring, unordered (!) keys, all values are strings (I suspect there are more bad things beyond that). Why not use `JsonObject` for such a case to preserve order and save on unnecessary serialization, or make a DTO class to hold all possible fields with proper types? 2) The issue you've faced with is not reproducible on my `1.8.0_191`. Are you sure your Android `HashMap` implementation preserves `null` values?

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try to your code (just replaced your variable with string value as your Map)

I got all the key. So no idea what's wrong with you 555

```
{"area":"area","patientName":"name","gender":"gender","patientId":null,"city":"city","tagColor":"tagColor","patientUhid":"uhid","mobileNumber":"phone","profilePic":null,"diagnosis":"diagnosis","treatments":"treatment","doctorId":"Prefs.getString","age":"age"}


String jsonStrReq = null;
        Map<String, String> patient1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        patient1.put("diagnosis", "diagnosis");
        patient1.put("doctorId", "Prefs.getString");
        patient1.put("patientId", null);
        patient1.put("patientName", "name");
        patient1.put("patientUhid", "uhid");
        patient1.put("mobileNumber", "phone");
        patient1.put("age", "age");
        patient1.put("gender", "gender");
        patient1.put("area", "area");
        patient1.put("city", "city");
        patient1.put("tagColor", "tagColor");
        patient1.put("treatments", "treatment");
        patient1.put("profilePic", null);
        Gson gsonReq = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        jsonStrReq = gsonReq.toJson(patient1);
        DebugLog.send(jsonStrReq);
```

Comment: implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

Comment: I tried new ArrayMap<>() from androidx collection (which is better for you). Same, I got everything, {"treatments":"treatment","gender":"gender","profilePic":null,"tagColor":"tagColor","patientId":null,"age":"age","area":"area","city":"city","patientName":"name","patientUhid":"uhid","doctorId":"Prefs.getString","diagnosis":"diagnosis","mobileNumber":"phone"}

Comment: I used the same code which you have added. I am not getting all of them.

Comment: I got it fixed. It is calling internally another method which created the problem. I really overlooked that. my bad. @Teddy Smith thanks for the help.